# Recording the optimal grid path for minimum cost

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic, dynamic-programming

So I have a 2D matrix, and I'm supposed to record the path which gives the minimum cost. I can only move down or right. Example:

```
2 4 1
3 7 6
3 8 9

Output: right right down down
```

My code gives the incorrect answers but I'm not able to spot why. I've also attached my code below:

```
public static List<String> optimalGridPath(int[][] grid) {

    ArrayList<String> answers = new ArrayList<String>();
    //TODO
    int gridRows = grid.length-1;
    int gridColumns = grid[0].length-1;

    int solutionGrid[][] = new int[gridRows+1][gridColumns+1];

    for (int i = 0; i <= gridRows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= gridColumns; j++) {
            if (i > 0 && j > 0)
                solutionGrid[i][j] = grid[i][j] +
                        Math.min(solutionGrid[i-1][j], solutionGrid[i][j-1]);
            else if (j == 0 && i == 0)
                solutionGrid[i][j] = grid[i][j];
            else if (j > 0)
                solutionGrid[i][j] = grid[i][j] + solutionGrid[i][j-1];
            else
                solutionGrid[i][j] = grid[i][j] + solutionGrid[i-1][j];
        }
    }

    while (gridRows != 0 && gridColumns != 0) {
        if (gridColumns == 0) {
            answers.add("down");
            gridRows--;
        }
        else if (gridRows == 0) {
            answers.add("right");
            gridColumns--;
        }
        else {
            if (solutionGrid[gridRows][gridColumns-1] <
                    solutionGrid[gridRows-1][gridColumns]) {
                answers.add("right");
                gridColumns--;
            }
            else {
                answers.add("down");
                gridRows--;
            }
        }
    }

    return answers;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of your solution appears to be correct, but the second part is not.

After the execution of your nested for loops, each position within your solutionGrid will be populated with the minimum cost to get to that position.

Therefore to determine the minimum cost path from the start to the finish, you should begin at the finish, and move left or up until you reach the start. You should move left when the position in the solution grid to the left of current position is less than the position in the solution grid above your current position.

You have done this, but instead of declaring that the correct path is to move left or up, you are declaring that you are moving right or down.

Because your answer list should dictate how to get to the finish from the start, your answer list is correct, but in reverse order.

Fix your program by calling

```
answers.insert(0, "right")
```

and

```
answers.insert(0, "down")
```

instead of using the "add" method - which will append to the end of your array list.

Comment: It's so stupid to not realize the mistake here.....it works perfectly now. Thanks!